# parse a query in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, qs

I need to convert a query string into an object, but with the respective data types. Let me explain it better: I use a table from an external service that generates filters when I add them. I need to put these filters into a query string and then read them back. When I read them back, I need each type to return to its initial state. For example, if before putting the query in the query string I have `{ foo: 10 }`, I need it to have the same thing when reading it back and not `{ foo: "10" }`. However, we know that the query string is, in fact, a string, and when I convert it back, the values of the JSON attributes are still strings. I'm not asking you to create a method for me that does this, but I would like to know if you know of a simpler way, such as some utility.

I started writing this method:

```
const parseStringToJson = (str: string | null | undefined): object => {
  // str is skip=0&take=10
  const parsedJSON: any = QueryString.parse(str || {});
  // parsedJSON is { skip: "0", take: "10"}

  const convertDataType = (data: object | null): void => {
    Object.entries(data || {}).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let isNumber = (typeof value === 'number' || (typeof value === 'string' && !isNaN(parseFloat(value))));
      let isBoolean = value === 'true' || value === 'false';
      //value is number
      if (isNumber) {
        return (parsedJSON[key] = Number(value));
      }
      //value is boolean
      if (isBoolean) {
        return (parsedJSON[key] = value === 'true');
      }
      //value is string
      if (typeof value === 'string' && !isNumber) {
        return (parsedJSON[key] = value);
      }
    });
  };

  convertDataType(parsedJSON);
  // parsedJSON is { skip: 0, take: 10}
  return parsedJSON;
};
```

Where QueryString is imported from [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

This works only with one level objects, but I need to do it deep inside. Also Manage arrays.

So before I starting doing that, Do you have a better idea to do so?

Comment: "*we know that the query string is, in fact, a string, and when I convert it back, the values of the JSON attributes are still strings*" that doesn't sound correct. [JSON does differentiate between strings and numbers](https://jsbin.com/koqopixage/edit?js,console). What possible way to do deserialisation do you use which doesn't? What does `QueryString.parse(str || {});` do? From the name, I don't expect it to handle JSON. Are you *sure* you handle JSON data? See [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Comment: A sample JSON string passed to your perhaps poorly named `str` might help here

Comment: "into a JSON object" JSON is a string, perhaps you meant a JavaScript object?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss a sample str is this one: `skip=0&take=10`. And yes i meant javascript object

Comment: That is not valid JSON - but also edit your question to enhance clarity and best relay information not add a comment here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Maybe the question is not written well... str actually is a query string `string` not a JSON. the `parsedJSON` is.

Comment: @VLAZ str is not a stringified json, in fact. I added some further informations

Comment: There's no JSON involved then. `parsedJSON` is a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Loudrous "*str actually is a query string string not a JSON. the parsedJSON is.*" it isn't. Again see [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Comment: I added and updated the tag for qs as that will probably enhance this and other uses of that.

Comment: Trying to work from *the value as a string* what the type of the value is, is backwards. You can have a property which is text, like `{ searchString: "123" }` yet if you try to check whether it contains only numbers and conclude from that check that it's a numeric property, then after deserialisation you'd get `{ searchString: 123 }` and that's not what you want. Since you seem to have *known properties*, just convert based on the property name.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss by json in fact i meant javascript objects.

Comment: @Loudrous protip: don't, because they're completely different things. JSON is a string representation _of_ JavaScript data, so you cannot use the terms interchangeably if you want to be understood. The only other thing that the term "JSON" can be used for is if you're talking about the JavaScript built-in global by that name, which houses the `stringify` and `parse` functions to turn JS data into their equivalent JSON-spec-conformant strings, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `parsedJSON` is not JSON, it's already a plain object, and so what you're asking seems to be a poorly phrased "how do I automatically convert any string values to other datatypes if that's what they are, no matter how deep they live in an object".

Ironically, one of the answers here (if you don't want to use a schema library, which you probably should) is to create an *actual* JSON string representation of your object, [using a replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#replacer) that converts values on the fly (because JSON.stringify is a tree-walker) and then parsing the result back from JSON to plain object:

```js
const someData = {
  cake: "yum",
  ingredients: {
    eggs: "3",
    oil: "false",
  },
  timings: ["short", "30", "short"]
};

function convert(key, value) {
  const type = typeof value;
  if (type === `string`) {
    const trimmed = value.trim();
    // for numbers, take advantage of type coercion:
    const num = parseFloat(trimmed);
    // note the intentional use of == instead of === here:
    if (trimmed == num) return num;
    // for booleans, just string compare:
    const lc = trimmed.toLowerCase();
    if (lc === `true`) return true;
    if (lc === `false`) return false;
  }
  // bonus feature: instead of crashing on functions, just ignore them!
  if (type === `function`) return;
  // Then let JSON.stringify deal with whatever's left.
  return value;
}

console.log(
  JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(someData, convert)
  )
);
```

Is this a *good* solution? No. Use a model/schema solution that can ingest string data and automatically convert it to the data type it should be. With model validation, so that if you're trying to create an incomplete or incompatible model instance, you can catch that and do whatever you need to do on input failure.

Is it a *fun* solution? Absolutely. Tree-walking an object using `JSON.stringify` is one of JS's hidden bonus features.

Answer (score -3):

An illustration of recognizing numbers from strings.

```js
let arr = ["one", "1", 0, 03, "02"];

arr.forEach(function(item){
if(isNaN(item)){
   console.log("The argument '" + item + "' cannot be converted to a number");
} else {

  console.log("Item '" + item + "' converts to " + Number(item));
}
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the user's question. It does not appear to even try. It simply shows how to parse a number from a string, something we have thousands of duplicates of.

Comment: @HereticMonkey small correction: shows how to parse a number *badly*. For `item = "0"` this code will claim that it cannot be converted to a number.